# Subclass a C++ abstract class in Java using JNI

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a C++ library that I have to use in an existing Android implementation. I'm using Android NDK and using the C++ classes via JNI.

However, I am not able to find how to subclass a C++ abstract class in Java using JNI.

Problems I face: 
My aim is to provide Java implementation for the virtual methods in C++ by subclassing the abstract C++ class.
I have loaded the native library and I'm trying to declare the native methods. 
The C++ methods have keyword 'virtual'. When I declare the native functions in Java after loading the C++ library, 'virtual' is not recognized. What is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated. I'm a newbie to JNI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html#wp725). You'll find that the JNI glue doesn't bond Java to C++ classes. For that, you'd need something built around JNI. [Jace](http://code.google.com/p/jace/wiki/Overview) is useful but doesn't go as far as you describe. My bet is that you won't find anything that avoids you manually creating a concrete C++ class and wrapping that.

Comment: @TomBlodget: Thanks! For creating wrappers, do you suggest some tool like SWIG or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at [BridJ](http://bridj.googlecode.com), too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's consider we have a C++ class:

```
class iVehicle
{
public:
   virtual void Run() {}; // not-pure virtual here for simplicity of a wrapper, but could be pure (see the end of the post)
   virtual int  GetSize() const; // we want to reuse it in Java
};
```

We want to create a class `Bot` in Java that extends class `iVehicle` in the sense that calls to `super` invoke the C++ code from `iVehicle::GetSize()` and, from the C++ point of view, we can use the instances of `Bot` as `iVehicle*` variables. That's tough since C++ provides no good built-in functionality for reflection.

**Here is one possible solution.**

To use C++ class in Java we need to generate a Java wrapper, i.e:

```
class iVehicle
{
   public void Run() { Native_Run(); }
   public int  GetSize() { return Native_GetSize(); }

   private native void Native_Run();
   private native int  Native_GetSize();

   // typecasted to pointer in C++
   private int NativeObjectHolder;

   // create C++ object
   native static private int CreateNativeObject();
}
```

The usage in Java is simple:

```
class Bot extends iVehicle
{
   public int GetSize()
   {
      if ( condition ) return 0;

      // call C++ code
      return super.GetSize();
   }
}
```

However, there is a C++ part to this code:

```
static jfieldID gNativeObjectHolderFieldID;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_iVehicle_Run( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
   int Value = env->GetIntField(thiz, gNativeObjectHolderFieldID);
   iVehicle* Obj = (iVehicle*)Obj;

   // todo: add checks here, for NULL and for dynamic casting

   Obj->Run();
}
```

The similar code is for `GetSize()`.

Then creating an instance of Java's `Bot` you have to call `CreateNativeObject()` and assign the returned value to the `NativeObjectHolder` field.

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_test_iVehicle_CreateNativeObject( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
   iVehicle* Obj = new iVehicle;
   return (int)Obj;    
}
```

So, this is the scheme. To make this work you will need to add the destruction code and to parse C++ classes to generate all this glue code.

**Added:**

In case where `iVehicle` is actually abstract you will have to generate a non-abstract wrapper that you are able to instantiate:

```
class iVehicle
{
   virtual void Run() = 0;
}

class iVehicle_Wrapper: public iVehicle
{
   virtual void Run() { ERROR("Abstract method called"); };
}
```

And instantiate `iVehicle_Wrapper` in `CreateNativeObject()`. Vuala! You have inherited an abstract C++ class in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. But, What if I want to provide a Java implementation for the abstract methods of the C++ class and want to use this Java subclass in C++ again?

Comment: Using Java subclasses in C++ is a sequel to this story. You need to generate a wrapper ``iVehicle_Wrapper`` which will hold an ID of Java's object/method and use JNI to call it.

Comment: I suggest you investigate *peer classes*.  You will a Java proxy class for `IVehicle` - which is an abstract class on the Java side of things mirroring the C++ methods.  On the C++ end, you want a concrete implementation of `iVehicle` that implements the all of the abstract virtual functions, forwarding them with JNI to the Java proxy.