# Java extends C++ class

Tags: java, c++, hibernate, java-native-interface

Suppose I have a C++ class `X`. I know I can call methods from `X` using JNI. But is it possible to create a Java class, by extending `X`? Is there a workaround?

The idea is to reuse data model classes from old C++ application, to extend these C++ classes as Hibernate Entity Model.

Comment: You'd need to write a Java class that interfaces with that C++ class using JNI. Then you can extend **that**.

Comment: MAYBE some simple example can be done, maybe not. I don't believe Your idea can be realised in complicated case. Both languages are TOTALLY diferent (reflection, language idioms, memory model and many more)

Comment: You need to create a JNI wrapper for your C++ class, then you can extend the wrapper by a Java class. A direct access between Java and C++, without JNI is not possible.

Comment: Please check this. It explains it well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110597/subclass-a-c-abstract-class-in-java-using-jni