# Android JNI calling inherited class' methods from C++

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am using a C++ library in Android. I have to inherit an abstract class from the library in Java and give the pointer to that class to the C++ side so that it can make callbacks.

### C++ side (library code)

```
class CallbackClass
{
    virtual void update(enum e) = 0;
}

class MainClass
{
    private CallbackClass* clientUpdater;

    void RegisterForSubscription(CallbackClass* receiver)
    { 
        clientUpdater = receiver;
        ......
    }

    void updateClient
    {
        clientUpdater->Update(status);
    }
}
```

I do not understand

1. How to inherit CallbackClass in Java and to implement update
   method
2. How to pass the pointer of the concrete class from java side to C++ side
       in method RegisterForSubscription
3. How 'update' method will get called from the c++ side

I am new to JNI so I would appreciate detailed answer with code

Comment: The answer is simple, you can't. Java and C++ are two separate world. JNI lets call C style native functions from the Java code and nothing more

Comment: In the following post Sergey K has answered a similar qustion and from that answer I feel this should be possible.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110597/subclass-a-c-abstract-class-in-java-using-jni?rq=1

Comment: You can make a mirror or wrapper Java class that calls functions of a C++ previously created object via JNI calls.